# I'm trying to add lists in lists by column. Is there a way to sum them with missing variables in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I had followed the book and can sum lists in lists by column but one of the test cases is missing variables in the list and I'm unable to move forward because I keep getting an index error.

The first initial_list works as it should giving `[3,6,9]`
The second one though should apparently give me `[3,4,9,4]`

```
list_initial = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3 ]]

list_initial = [[1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]


def column_sums(list_initial):

    column = 0
    list_new = []
    while column < len(list_initial):
        total = sum(row[column] for row in list_initial )
        list_new.append(total)
        column = column + 1
        print(list_new)

    column_sums(list_initial)
```

Comment: You are explaining yourself like a closed book, please be more specific about what you expect and what error your codes throws.

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively "transpose" your data so that rows become columns, and then use `itertools.zip_longest` with a `fillvalue` of 0, to sum across them, eg:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_initial = [[1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
summed = [sum(col) for col in zip_longest(*list_initial, fillvalue=0)]
# [3, 4, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That’s really interesting import I didn’t know about.

Comment: @NicholasWang It doesn't give you `[3,4,9,4]` as you state as expected output in your Q, but then I can't see how that's actually valid given the input.